# jquery table-less layout with rowspans

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using this question as a guide [Javascript work-around for display: table-cell in IE <= 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983305/javascript-work-around-for-display-table-cell-in-ie-7) however, I need to account for rowspans so I can process this html correctly in IE 7,8,9.

```
<div class="Table">
    <div  class="Row">
      <div class="RowSpan">
        This column should equal the height (no fixed-height allowed) of the 2 rows sitting to the right.
      </div>
      <div class="SubRow">
        <div class="Column">
          Here is some sample text1.1. And some additional sample text.
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
          Here is some sample text2.1. And some additional sample text.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="SubRow">
        <div class="Column">
          Here is some sample text1.2. And some additional sample text.
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
          Here is some sample text2.2. And some additional sample text.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div  class="Row">
      <div class="RowSpan">
        This column should equal the height (no fixed-height allowed) of the 2 rows sitting to the right.
      </div>
      <div class="SubRow">
        <div class="Column">
          Here is some sample text1.1. And some additional sample text.
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
          Here is some sample text2.1. And some additional sample text.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="SubRow">
        <div class="Column">
          Here is some sample text1.2. And some additional sample text.
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
          Here is some sample text2.2. And some additional sample text.
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>      
</div>
```

the css

```
<style>
.Table{
    display: table; width:300px; border: 1px solid black; border-spacing: 2px;
}
.Row{
    display: table-cell; border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: middle; float: left;
}
.RowSpan{
    display: table-cell; border: 1px solid black; vertical-align: middle;   
}
.SubRow{
    display: table-cell; width: 100px;
}
.Column{
    border: 1px solid black;margin: 2px;
}
</style>
```

I am looking for a jquery fix to the script outlined below.  This is not tabular data so I do not want to use tables.

```
$('<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>')
    .find('td')
        .eq(0)
            .append( $('.Row') )
            .end()
        .eq(1)
            .append( $('.RowSpan') )
            .end()
        .eq(2)
            .append( $('.SubRow') )
            .end()
        .eq(3)
            .append( $('.Column') )
            .end()
        .end()
    .appendTo($('.Table'));
```

Comment: If its supposed to look like a table, use a table. Doing it any other way is really a bad idea and a waste of time.

Comment: `if($.browser.msie)`- bad idea when it is supported in some versions, test for feature support , check out modernizer

Comment: @jon it's not tabular data, so I do not want to use tables

Comment: @charlietfl I will have to check this out, but instead of spending the time to implement an entire another framework, I am hoping to get this going with jquery

Comment: modernizer is not another framework, it doesn't do anything that jQuery does

Comment: @charlietfl cool, I will have to check that out, but it does not solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the sample you're working from. In that, the question was how do I draw that simple three column layout with a table instead if it's IE. The answerer's solution was:

```
$('<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>')
    .find('td')
        .eq(0)
            .append( $('#sidebar') )
            .end()
        .eq(1)
            .append( $('#main_content') )
            .end()
        .eq(2)
            .append( $('.aside_info') )
            .end()
        .end()
    .appendTo( $('#content') );
```

Here's that this means, written out algorithmically:

```
Within the string '<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>'
   Find all the elements that are 'TD's
       If it's the first TD, 
            Take the div ID'd "#sidebar" and place it in that TD
       If it's the second TD, 
            Take the div ID'd "#main_content" and place it in that TD
       If it's the third TD, 
            Take any and all divs classed ".aside_info" and place it in that TD
   Then take that whole string, that's now very long because it's got all my 
      content in it, and place it inside the newly empty div ID'd "#content"
```

And thusly converts a three column div layout to a three column table layout.

What you're doing in yours, is, algorythmically:

```
Within the string '<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>'
       Find all the elements that are 'TD's
           If it's the first TD, 
                Take any and all divs classed ".Row" and place it in that TD
           If it's the second TD, 
                Take any and all divs classed ".RowSpan" and place it in that TD
           If it's the third TD, 
                Take any and all divs classed ".SubRow" and place it in that TD
           If it's the fourth TD, 
                Take any and all divs classed ".Column" and place it .... 
                   er, well, it won't place them anywhere, because there 
                   is no fourth TD in that string.
       Then take that whole string, that's now very long because it's got 
          some of my content in it, and place it inside any and all divs 
          classed ".Table"
```

See why it's breaking? It doesn't match up.

To solve this:
First, note that they layout has to be the same, so if it's being programmatically drawn, and you don't know how many rows you'll have, it'll be different.
Second... really, there's got to be a better way. But, here ya go:

```
$('<table><tr><td rowspan=2></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td rowspan=2></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>')
        .find('td')
            .eq(0) //first td with a rowspan
                .append( $('.RowSpan').eq(0) )  // gotta insert the first one only
                .end()
            .eq(1)
                .append( $('.SubRow').eq(0).find('.Column').eq(0) ) // inserting the first column from the first sub row
                .end()
            .eq(2)
                .append( $('.SubRow').eq(0).find('.Column').eq(1) ) // inserting the second column from the first sub row
                .end()
            .eq(3)
                .append( $('.SubRow').eq(1).find('.Column').eq(0) ) // inserting the first column from the second sub row
                .end()
            .eq(4)
                .append( $('.SubRow').eq(1).find('.Column').eq(1) ) // inserting the second column from the second sub row
                .end()
            .eq(5)    //second td with a rowspan
                .append( $('.RowSpan').eq(1) )  // gotta insert the second RowSpan div
                .end()
            .eq(6)
                .append( $('.SubRow').eq(2).find('.Column').eq(0) ) // inserting the first column from the third sub row
                .end()
            .eq(7)
                .append( $('.SubRow').eq(2).find('.Column').eq(1) ) // inserting the second column from the third sub row
                .end()
            .eq(8)
                .append( $('.SubRow').eq(3).find('.Column').eq(0) ) // inserting the first column from the fourth sub row
                .end()
            .eq(9)
                .append( $('.SubRow').eq(3).find('.Column').eq(1) ) // inserting the second column from the fourth sub row
                .end()
            .end()
        .appendTo( $('#Table') );
```

That should do it, assuming I didn't screw up the syntax anywhere.